# ASP.NET compilationMode Auto vs Never

Tags: asp.net, web-config, compilation, compilationmode

Let's assume my ASPX page has no inline C# code blocks.

So, I can safely set

```
<pages compilationMode="Never" />
```

...in my web.config file and not worry about compilation errors.

Performance-wise, would there be any penalty to using the following setting?

```
<pages compilationMode="Auto" />
```

i.e. does the "auto" detection take any significant amount of time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The impact of **Auto** appears to be very little. (Although obviously more than **Never**).

If we examine the code in [System.Web.UI.TemplateParser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.templateparser.aspx), we see in `ImportSourceFile` that process is aborted early if mode is set to `Never`:

```
if (this.CompilationMode == CompilationMode.Never)
{
    return null;
}
```

Which is of course helpful, and definitely the lowest-impact. However, continuing through the routines in `TemplateParser`, we can see in `ParseStringInternal` the parser literally scans the loaded template searching for variations of `<%`:

```
if (!this.flags[2] && (match = BaseParser.aspCodeRegex.Match(text, startat)).Success)
{
    string str3 = match.Groups["code"].Value.Trim();
    if (str3.StartsWith("$", StringComparison.Ordinal))
    {
        this.ProcessError(SR.GetString("ExpressionBuilder_LiteralExpressionsNotAllowed", new object[] { match.ToString(), str3 }));
    }
    else
    {
        this.ProcessCodeBlock(match, CodeBlockType.Code, text);
    }
}
```

Note the `BaseParser.aspCodeRegex`, which is an instance of this pattern:

```
public AspCodeRegex()
{
    base.pattern = @"\G<%(?!@)(?<code>.*?)%>";
    ...
}
```

If it encounters none, it simply moves on. The searching is a fairly inexpensive operation - the biggest hit is when code blocks are actually found, compiling them.

Comment: How were you able to view the code of System.Web.UI.TemplateParser?
Great answer BTW.

Comment: @frankadelic Cheers! I use **Reflector** (http://red-gate.com/products/reflector) - the best documentation is the code itself :)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure I agree with the suggestion that **Auto** should be more performant than **Always**. There's a [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580110/sharepoint-virtualpathproviders-and-application-restarts) question on this and I think that ultimately '**Auto**' (and non-compiled pages, in general) were introduced as a means to offer better scalability, not necessarily better performance (beyond the initial compilation/parse overhead).

If **Auto** was more performant in every scenario, why wouldn't it be the default?

Applications that have a small, fixed number of assemblies would benefit from the standard **Always** setting and site-wide pre-compilation; for CMS-esque scenarios, like SharePoint, where pages are changed at run-time, **Auto** is the only option, out of shear necessity.

What I'm at a loss to explain in our scenario (few hundred assemblies, not changing at run-time) is why **% Time in JIT** is fluctuating and occasionally higher than 60%, long after the app has been warmed up and even with site-wide pre-compilation? If this common with 200-500 assembly deployments, then I can see the benefit of **Auto** in those scenarios as well.

Comment: Interesting stuff... I am using "Auto" to get around app domain restarts when my ASPX pages change. However, I still have the issue when .resx files change http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535027

Comment: Funny you should mention that - looks like we're wrestling with the same issues!  There's a straightforward workaround for resx files (see the answer posted).

Answer (score 0):

**Auto** should be more performant than **Always**, and is a safe failsafe for when you do add inline C# code.

Extra time will be spent determining if a page needs to be compiled, which adds a little overhead in comparison to the **Never** option.