# Help debugging - when does the Application_Start run in global.asax file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, debugging, global-asax

Here's the snippet from my Global.asax:

```
<script runat="server">  
    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        // log this call
        EventLogger.Log("ApplicationStart");
    }

    void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        // log what the user is doing
        UsageLogger.Log(UsageLogger.GetServerVariables());
    }
</script>
```

When I open the log, I see many ApplicationStart calls interspersed with usage calls.  Why does my application seem to restart so much?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Application_Start fires once when the app starts up.  Application_BeginRequest happens on every request.

This [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/tess/archive/2006/08/02/asp-net-case-study-lost-session-variables-and-appdomain-recycles.aspx) helped in a simliar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535027/app-domain-restarts-when-resx-file-changes-any-way-to-avoid-this/1535491#1535491).

[ASP.NET Case Study: Lost session variables and appdomain recycles](http://blogs.msdn.com/tess/archive/2006/08/02/asp-net-case-study-lost-session-variables-and-appdomain-recycles.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

That depends on the IIS configuration. the default is 20 minutes. The application will automatically restart if no request during this time period.

Comment: Could you point me to some documentation on this?  It would be very helpful, thanks.