# How to save object variable for all Users of ASP.NET Application to use that is fired up once

Tags: c#, asp.net, persistence, global-asax

I am trying to have a variable that is an object exist once on the server for an ASP.Net Application. 
I want to fire it up and then allow every user of the application to have it.

My understanding is that the `Global.asax` file contains a method called `Application_Start` that starts up every time a user calls for the first time. And it has a method `Application_BeginRequest` for each request.
The method `Application_Start` does not suit my needs as it is once per user.

Is it possible to somehow have an object for all users?

Storing a global variable in a static class will not work either as it once instance per user of the application.

The reason for the need is we are trying to use a new product and improve performance(speed) and the declaration and initialization of this object is a performance cost we are trying to circumvent.

[Stackoverflow-Global.asax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567726/help-debugging-when-does-the-application-start-run-in-global-asax-file) does not really help me and

[Stackoverflow-SessionVariables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24148305/site-wide-variables-per-user) does not solve my need

Is there a way of storing an object variable in a file available for the whole pool of users? I am at a a loss as tho the solution?

Comment: Why not use `MemoryCache`?

Comment: @JohanP I had not heard of MemoryCache until you mentioned it and I am looking into it. Can I store object there and access them from my ASP.Net application?

Comment: I think it is just called `Cache` in asp.net webforms. It will sit in memory on the server. If you have a web farm setup, then each machine will have to create the heavy object.

Comment: @JohanP Cache seems like it would suit our needs. We will give it a go.

Comment: @JohanP Thanks for that. I am getting really good speeds for retrieving the object from Cache. Do you want to post that as an answer as I will accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/18c1wd61%28v%3Dvs.140%29) to cache you application data machine wide.