# Validating with localized strings

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, localization

I am trying to localize validation messages in an ASP MVC3 model class.

```
[RegularExpression(@"^\d*$", ErrorMessage = "Has to be numeric.")]
public Int32? X{ get; set; }
```

We have to retrieve the localized strings from a database using a method from a given resource handler, so no common resource files are possible.

What is the prefered way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can set the resource key on the vaildation attribute, along with the resource type (RESX).

```
Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required", 
           ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Validation))]
[DataType(DataType.Text)]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

Note one limitation is if you are using a custom resource provider. Unfortunately there's is no provision to plug this in. I came up with solution for this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7207608/asp-net-localization-changing-resources-without-restarting-the-application/7214340#7214340), but if you are using standard RESX approach then it's not necessary.